# How can i eliminate dups?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

```
select C.Id as candidateId,C.Name, C.Phone, Status.ResultStatusText , Status.TimeStamp,  Status.notes ,
            (Select count(*) from CandidateCallHistory  where CandiateId =  candidateId) AS numbCalls,
            (SELECT SUBSTRING((SELECT ',' + Name
                FROM Jobs  
                WHERE Id in (select value from fn_Split(c.JobIds,','))
                FOR XML PATH('')),2,200000)) AS jobsList
    from  Candidate2 C
    outer APPLY  (select top 1 CH.CandiateId, CH.ResultStatusText , CH.TimeStamp , CH.notes  
                    from CandidateCallHistory CH    
                    where CH.CandiateId = C.Id          
                    order by TimeStamp desc) as Status 
    where Status.ResultStatusText <> 'completed' and Status.ResultStatusText <> 'canceled' and c.isactive = 1
```

I have multiple records in the `CandidateCallHistory` table and seems this is causing issue with the outer apply ( i may be wrong) as it should only get the most recent record in the table since it selects top 1.

Comment: You need to provide sample data and results, so we unerstand what you mean by "dups".

Comment: I would guess the duplicates are in `Candidate2` as you explicitely `SELECT TOP 1 ...` in the derived table you do an `OUTER APPLY` with. Some sample data and result that shows duplicates would help for us to understand the issue.

Comment: What is this about `CandiateId =  candidateId`?  I guess `CandiateId` comes from `CandidateCallHistory` but from where do you get the column `candidateId`?

Answer (score -2):

Try to add distinct in first line after select:

```
select distinct [...]
```

Comment: this just masks the issue. the answer is to resolve the joins so there is no dups